# Change Footer Color in Flutter. (persistentFooterButtons)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `persistentFooterButtons` option for my `Scaffold`.

```
persistentFooterButtons: [
        FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "editself",
            child: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () {
              print(InterfaceViewRoute);
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, InterfaceViewRoute, arguments: "-1");
            }),
        FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "scanneredit",
          child: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded),
          onPressed: () => _scan(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

But now the whole background is filled there. See image:

[image: How its look like]

Is there a way to make this background transparent so that you can see the list all the way down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transparent Footer with Floating Action buttons**

[image]

**This is a Code Snippet.**

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 40.0,
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              tooltip: 'Home',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            FloatingActionButton(
              tooltip: 'Details',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.details,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            FloatingActionButton(
              tooltip: 'Bar Chart',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.bar_chart_outlined,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            FloatingActionButton(
              tooltip: 'Settings',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can you please provide a GitHub link to this UI?

Comment: This was a private repository for a company.

Comment: If you need help, I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put Row in floatingActionButton?

```
floatingActionButton: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton(
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              FloatingActionButton(
              ),
            ],
          )),
```

Comment: Yes, but it can´t only be assined to a ActionButton. But with `persistentFooterButtons` it works. idk

Comment: `persistentFooterButtons` is not overlap with the body its below the widget `body`. If you want to be able to see it, the only thing you can use is the `floatingActionButton` in Scaffold that is floating at the top of the body.

That's why I use the Row to wrap two button inside. You actually may add more button or other widget there

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can´t use a Row at `floatingActionButton` ...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `bottomNavigationBar` of Scaffold

```
...
      extendBody: true, // if you want body to be extended below buttons
      bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: TextButton(child: Text('button'), onPressed: () {}), //or row of buttons
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.transparent, //background color
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 3),
        ),
      ),
...
```